# In Javascript, how do I write one function that will effect multiple buttons, each with their own separate arrays?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I am currently setting up an application with three separate buttons, each which is supposed to randomly select an element from an array specific to that button. I've successfully coded it with individual functions for each button, but I was wondering if there is a way to condense it into a single function that can apply to all three buttons.

This is my current Javascript:

```
const greyButton = document.querySelector('#grey');
greyButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let grey = ['Statblocks/Grey/badger.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/giantrat.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/badger.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/boar.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/panther.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/gitant badger.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/dire wolf.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/giant elk.png']
  
  for (i=0;i<grey.length;i++){
    let greyBalls = grey[Math.floor(Math.random() * grey.length)];
    document.getElementById('greyBall').src = greyBalls;
  }
});

const rustButton = document.querySelector('#rust');
rustButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let rust = ['Statblocks/Rust/rat.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/owl.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/mastiff.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/goat.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/giant goat.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/giant boar.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/lion.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/brown bear.png']
  
  for (i=0;i<rust.length;i++){
    let rustBalls = rust[Math.floor(Math.random() * rust.length)];
    document.getElementById('rustBall').src = rustBalls;
  }
});

const tanButton = document.querySelector('#tan');
tanButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let tan = ['Statblocks/Tan/jackal.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/ape.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/baboon.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/axe beak.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/black bear.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/giant weasel.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/giant hyena.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/tiger.png']
  
  for (i=0;i<tan.length;i++){
    let tanBalls = tan[Math.floor(Math.random() * tan.length)];
    document.getElementById('tanBall').src = tanBalls;
  }
});
```

And the connected HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <h1>Grey Bag of Tricks</h1>
                <button class="button" id='grey'>Draw from the Bag</button>
                <img src="" alt="" id="greyBall">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h1>Rust Bag of Tricks</h1>
                <button class="button" id='rust'>Draw from the Bag</button>
                <img src="" alt="" id="rustBall">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <h1>Tan Bag of Tricks</h1>
                <button class="button" id='tan'>Draw from the Bag</button>
                <img src="" alt="" id="tanBall">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: If you condensed them into a single function, that single function would have to have conditional logic inside it to perform different logic for each path, since each element has its own set of urls.  You could do it, but I think it would just make it less readable.

Comment: Excellent thank you! I wasn't sure if it was possible to do, and if the necessary logic would reduce readability then I think I will leave it as is.

Comment: Changing up the markup, you might could make it easier to reduce.  Let me see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Taplar He wants a single function that he can call three times with different arguments, which is totally the appropriate solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var urlsByColor = {
  grey: ['Statblocks/Grey/badger.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/giantrat.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/badger.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/boar.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/panther.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/gitant badger.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/dire wolf.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/giant elk.png'],
  rust: ['Statblocks/Rust/rat.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/owl.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/mastiff.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/goat.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/giant goat.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/giant boar.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/lion.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/brown bear.png'],
  tan: ['Statblocks/Tan/jackal.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/ape.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/baboon.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/axe beak.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/black bear.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/giant weasel.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/giant hyena.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/tiger.png']
};

function changeBall (e) {
  const urls = urlsByColor[e.target.id];
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length);
  const randomUrl = urls[randomIndex];
  const associatedBall = e.target.closest('.column').querySelector('.ball');
  
  console.log(`change ${e.target.id} to ${randomUrl}`);
  associatedBall.src = randomUrl;
  console.log(associatedBall);
}

[...document.querySelectorAll('.color.button')].forEach(button =>
  button.addEventListener('click', changeBall)
);
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <h1>Grey Bag of Tricks</h1>
    <button class="button color" id='grey'>Draw from the Bag</button>
    <img src="" alt="" class="ball" id="greyBall">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h1>Rust Bag of Tricks</h1>
    <button class="button color" id='rust'>Draw from the Bag</button>
    <img src="" alt="" class="ball" id="rustBall">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h1>Tan Bag of Tricks</h1>
    <button class="button color" id='tan'>Draw from the Bag</button>
    <img src="" alt="" class="ball" id="tanBall">
  </div>
</div>
```

Ok so a few things changed.

- I extracted the lists of urls out to a map, that can use the id of the button to lookup what urls to use
- The markup for the buttons and balls changed to have common classes for finds and lookups
- When a click happens, we get the urls by the button id
- We then get a random index like was done before
- We get the random assoicated url for that index
- We find the ball that is associated with the button contextually by the parent column class
- And finally we change the ball's url

Comment: Something I'm noticing is it does occasionally return a blank image now though. Unsure exactly how to remedy that.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you put the similar repeated part in a function, then you abstract all the parts that are different in each usage by replacing them with parameters to the function:

```
function addHandler(buttonSelector, ballImages, ballId) {
  const button = document.querySelector(buttonSelector);
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    for (let i=0; i<ballImages.length; i++) {
      let ball = ballImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * ballImages.length)];
      document.getElementById(ballId).src = ball;
    }
  });
}
```

so that you can call it like

```
addHandler('#grey', ['Statblocks/Grey/badger.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/giantrat.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/badger.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/boar.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/panther.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/gitant badger.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/dire wolf.png', 'Statblocks/Grey/giant elk.png'], 'greyBall');
addHandler('#rust', ['Statblocks/Rust/rat.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/owl.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/mastiff.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/goat.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/giant goat.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/giant boar.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/lion.png', 'Statblocks/Rust/brown bear.png'], 'rustBall');
addHandler('#tan', ['Statblocks/Tan/jackal.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/ape.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/baboon.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/axe beak.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/black bear.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/giant weasel.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/giant hyena.png', 'Statblocks/Tan/tiger.png'], 'tanBall');
```

That's still some duplication though. We can avoid that by doing extra processing on the data so that we can pass simpler values:

```
function addHandler(id, imageNames) {
  const buttonSelector = '#' + id;
  const ballImages = imageNames.map(name => `Statblocks/${id[0].toUpperCase()+id.slice(1)}/${name}.png}`);
  const ballId = id + 'Ball';

  … // rest as before
}

addHandler('grey', ['badger', 'giantrat', 'badger', 'boar', 'panther', 'gitant badger', 'dire wolf', 'giant elk']);
addHandler('rust', ['rat', 'owl', 'mastiff', 'goat', 'giant goat', 'giant boar', 'lion', 'brown bear']);
addHandler('tan', ['jackal', 'ape', 'baboon', 'axe beak', 'black bear', 'giant weasel', 'giant hyena', 'tiger']);
```

Last I'd change the `querySelector` to a `getElementById` lookup, and remove the unnecessary loop, and we arrive at

```
function addHandler(id, imageNames) {
  const ballImages = imageNames.map(name => `Statblocks/${id[0].toUpperCase()+id.slice(1)}/${name}.png}`);
  const button = document.getElementById(id);
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let ball = ballImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * ballImages.length)];
    document.getElementById(id + 'Ball').src = ball;
  });
}

addHandler('grey', ['badger', 'giantrat', 'badger', 'boar', 'panther', 'gitant badger', 'dire wolf', 'giant elk']);
addHandler('rust', ['rat', 'owl', 'mastiff', 'goat', 'giant goat', 'giant boar', 'lion', 'brown bear']);
addHandler('tan', ['jackal', 'ape', 'baboon', 'axe beak', 'black bear', 'giant weasel', 'giant hyena', 'tiger']);
```