# Is there a simpler (shorter) notation for writing this click event / function(s) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, onclicklistener

I am working on a [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) map and I have 37 markers on the map. Is there any shorter way of writing the below code or do I have to write click event 37 times like I did below with the first 2 markers?

```
const marker1 = L.marker([45.899491, 16.844165],{icon:leafletIcon}).addTo(bjelovar);
const marker2 = L.marker([45.896034, 16.845399],{icon:leafletIcon}).addTo(bjelovar);

marker1.on('click',function(){

    const content1 = '<div class="modal-text">Ulica je nosila naziv po Josipu Blivajsu do početka 1930-tih godina kada postaje Ulica Frana Supila. Vodi od središnjeg Trga Eugena Kvaternika do Šetališta dr. Ivše Lebovića odnosno Dječjeg odjela knjižnice. Neke od najznačajnijih građevina svakako su njezine uglovnice: nekadašnje svratište Zvijezda te kuća Ivana Ružića uz trg, zgrada Prve hrvatske štedionice, zgrada Kraljevskog poštanskog i brzojavnog ureda te gostiona J. Svobode na kraju ulice.</div> <img class="modal-img" src="./images/full/Blivajsova/01 Blivajsova ulica (oko 1900).jpg"> <img class="modal-img" src="./images/full/Blivajsova/02 Blivajsova ulica (oko 1902).jpg"> <img class="modal-img" src="./images/full/Blivajsova/03 Blivajsova ulica (oko 1907).jpg">';
    
    L.control.window(bjelovar,{
        title: 'Blivajsova ulica'
    })
        .content(content1)
        .show()
});

marker2.on('click',function(){

    const content2 = '<div class="modal-text">Prethodno ulica Teodora Georgijevića, dobila je ime Tomaša Masaryka početkom 1930-tih godina. Formirana je širenjem grada u jugoistočnom pravcu, uvjetovanim dolaskom željeznice. Zamišljena je kao reprezentativan pojas historicističkih i secesijskih stambenih vila s kovanim ogradama i zelenilom prema ulici.</div> <img class="modal-img" src="./images/full/Cetvrt/01 Četvrt vila (oko 1909).jpg"> <img class="modal-img" src="./images/full/Cetvrt/02 Četvrt vila (oko 1912).jpg"> <img class="modal-img" src="./images/full/Cetvrt/03 Četvrt vila (oko 1914).jpg">';
    
    L.control.window(bjelovar,{
        title: 'Četvrt vila'
    })
        .content(content2)
        .show()
});
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65044445/1048572). Or use an array of objects.

Comment: Or add the listener to the container and act on the event target referencing the content and title conditionally. (Bergi's linked answer is a nice solution)

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. Also a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to store all the data for each marker in an object, then just loop through that. Something like this:

```js
// Each marker identified by its title
const markerData = {
  'Blivajsova ulica': {
    content: '<div class="modal-text">Ulica je ...',
    coords: [45.899491, 16.844165]
  },
  'Četvrt vila' : {
    content: '<div class="modal-text">Prethodno ulica T...',
    coords: [45.896034, 16.845399]
  }
  
  // Add all the data
}

for (const [title, data] of Object.entries(markerData)) {

  const marker = L.marker(data.coords,{icon:leafletIcon}).addTo(bjelovar);

  marker1.on('click',function(){

    L.control.window(bjelovar, { title })
      .content(data.content)
      .show()
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the markers to a featuregroup and then read out the markers and add the listener in a loop.

```
const group = L.featureGroup().addTo(bjelovar);
const marker1 = L.marker([45.899491, 16.844165],{icon:leafletIcon}).addTo(group);
const marker2 = L.marker([45.896034, 16.845399],{icon:leafletIcon}).addTo(group);

group.eachLayer((layer)=>{
  layer.on('click',function(){
    const content1 = '<div class="modal-text">Ulica je nosila naziv po Josipu Blivajsu do početka 1930-tih godina kada postaje Ulica Frana Supila. Vodi od središnjeg Trga Eugena Kvaternika do Šetališta dr. Ivše Lebovića odnosno Dječjeg odjela knjižnice. Neke od najznačajnijih građevina svakako su njezine uglovnice: nekadašnje svratište Zvijezda te kuća Ivana Ružića uz trg, zgrada Prve hrvatske štedionice, zgrada Kraljevskog poštanskog i brzojavnog ureda te gostiona J. Svobode na kraju ulice.</div> <img class="modal-img" src="./images/full/Blivajsova/01 Blivajsova ulica (oko 1900).jpg"> <img class="modal-img" src="./images/full/Blivajsova/02 Blivajsova ulica (oko 1902).jpg"> <img class="modal-img" src="./images/full/Blivajsova/03 Blivajsova ulica (oko 1907).jpg">';  
    L.control.window(bjelovar,{
        title: 'Blivajsova ulica'
    })
    .content(content1)
    .show()
  });

});
```

Comment: Notice that also the title and contents are different

Answer (score 0):

When we need to get rid of repetitive actions, we function them away (sample code):

```
[
  {lat: 45.899491, lon: 16.844165, title: 'Blivajsova ulica', text: '...'},
  {lat: 45.896034, lon: 16.844399, title: 'Četvrt vila', text: '...'},
]
.forEach(({lat, lon, title, text}) => {
   L.marker([lat, lon], {icon:leafletIcon}).addTo(bjelovar)
   .on('click',
      () => L.control.window(bjelovar, {title}).content(text).show()
   )
})
```

Comment: Also seems like a neat way but I can't get it to show markers on the map.

Comment: Then the problem is outside of the code snippet that you show us.

Comment: Keldan Chapman's solution works flawlessly.